# error: missing argument list for method sql, when trying to access config options

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to inspect or set [`spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options) in my spark shell (2.3.1), but am getting

```
error: missing argument list for method sql in class SparkSession
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `sql _` or `sql(_)` instead of `sql`.
```

I think the suggested remedy does not apply because I am not trying to invoke the method `spark.sql("select * from mytable")`, I want to access an attribute of it.

How can I get the value of this config?

Answer (score 0):

Had to infer the existence of this method because I can't find it in their documentation, but

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")
```

is the counterpart to

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")
```

where `spark.conf.set` is casually used elsewhere in the docs in a PySpark example.